# Eclipse RCP E4 Part Sash Container Default Minimum

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I have two parts in a part sash, one having a `Container Data` value of 500, the other 9500.  This is intentional to create a thin part for use as a status window of sorts.  Upon application start-up the sash is sized properly, but if the sash divider bar is moved just a pixel, the sash jumps to a default minimum value; this is undesirable.  We are using SWT as the renderer and not JavaFX.  Embedding the status window in a trim bar is out of the question as the trim bar is used for other things (otherwise I would just do that and forget about resizing it).

Question: is there a way to change this default minimum value or something else I can do to prevent this jumping in sash size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `minSashPercent` value in  `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashLayout` is responsible for this.

There doesn't appear to be a way to set this. So you would have to use a [custom renderer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) extending the `SashRenderer` and use a modified version of the SashLayout class.

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Not an ideal solution, but I will look in to it.